# How do I nest a substitute formula inside an index function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on an excel sheet, using an Index match function. Since I want it to increment columns when I copy the formula down, I have used the formula below:

```
=INDEX(CLASSIFCATION!SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,ROW(A2),4),1,""):SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,ROW(A2),4),1,""),MATCH(DISTRIBUTION!P$19,CLASSIFCATION!$A:$A,0))
```

To provide some more detail:

When pasted in row P20, the formula should be:

```
=INDEX(CLASSIFCATION!B:B,MATCH(DISTRIBUTION!P$19,CLASSIFCATION!$A:$A,0))
```

In row 21 it should be

```
=INDEX(CLASSIFCATION!C:C,MATCH(DISTRIBUTION!P$19,CLASSIFCATION!$A:$A,0))
```

and so on..

where CLASSIFICATION and DISTRIBUTION are two sheets in the same workbook.

I get an error saying "There's a problem with this formula". I'm not able to use the evaluate formula to check what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the full range in the INDEX then use the third Criterion to tell the INDEX which Column:

```
=INDEX(CLASSIFCATION!A:XFD,MATCH(DISTRIBUTION!P$19,CLASSIFCATION!$A:$A,0),ROW(2:2))
```

Now as the formula is copied/dragged down it will refer to the next column.

Another method would be to use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(DISTRIBUTION!P$19,A:XFD,ROW(2:2),FALSE)
```

This will do the same.

---

As to why your formula does not work `ADDRESS()`, which is volatile and should be avoided when using more than a handful, returns a string.  A concatenated string is not a viable range reference.  You would need to wrap the whole in INDIRECT which is also volatile:

```
INDIRECT("CLASSIFCATION!" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,ROW(A2),4),1,"") & ":" & SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,ROW(A2),4),1,""))
```

But outside this being verbose it uses volatile functions which re-calc every time Excel re-calcs not just when the underlying data changes.

Another shorter volatile method is OFFSET:

```
OFFSET(CLASSIFCATION!A:A,0,ROW(1:1))
```

While this is shorter than the INDEX it too is Volatile and if can be should be avoided when using in multiple formula.

Comment: Both methods worked perfectly. Using the Indirect function worked well too!  Thank you!